# How did n2 / n lg n = n / n lg n?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I recently stumbled on this equation

[image]

so how did $n^2 / n \lg n  = n / n \lg n$ ?

Comment: divide by $n$ the numerator and denominator

Comment: can you use $$\LaTeX$$ please?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Hi sorry. I don't know how yet do you have any reference for latex?

Comment: @ArnaldoNascimento why divide both sides n? for simplification?

Comment: yes! just simplification!

Comment: Here is the [$\LaTeX$ guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read your image closer.

$\dfrac{n^2}{n\lg n}$ did not become $\dfrac{n}{n\lg n}$. It became $\dfrac{n}{\lg n}$, by dividing both numerator and denominator by $n$.